# jit debugging was initiated by the user account - What is the issue?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, jit

We have a WPF application...which is deployed using click once approach.
We deployed it in a intranet webserver...and people can install it in their machine from a link available in a web page (index.html).

One of hour team member got the following error

Jit debugging failed with following error: Access denied
jit debugging was initiated by the user account "abc\abc918"
Click the documentation index for "just in time debugging errors for more information"

Please help me to understand what is this error about. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically a result of having `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` in your code.  This requires the current user to part of the "Debugger Users" group in order to function.  If you are not, then you'll receive this error.

This frequently occurs on hosted ASP.Net sites - see this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817035) for details.

Comment: @Anish: Yes - but only if you're deploying a Debug build - in a Release build (with DEBUG not defined), it shouldn't matter...